# Mostrar solo una parte del valor de un input

Tags: php, mysql, input

quiero hacer algo pero no se como, por eso acudo a ustedes..

Tengo un input que muestra diferentes valores, los mismos los llamo de una bd asi:

```
<input type="text" name="tkn_sms" id="tkn_sms" value="<?php echo $row ['tkn_sms'];?>" class="form-control" >
```

Efectivamente el input me muestra el valor que viene desde la bd asi:

`JVGCFGCJKJhvghjhCFChVkjhbJvgVJvkgcvgjcfc`

Ahora o que quiero es que en el input, solo me muestre parte de este resultado pero lo demas no, algo asi:

`JVGCFGCJKJhvghjhC....`

De antemano agradezco a quien me pueda dar luces sobre el tema, gracias.

Comment: Prueba con una [subcadena](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php).

Comment: Y no lo puedes hacer con estilos para achicar el recuadro del input con width y para que no se vea lo que sobresalga del input le das overflow-x: Hidden;. El problema de la subcadena es que pierdes el valor real del input. Estos atributo los puedes poner como una clase de estilo o añadiendo la etiqueta style. Solo tienes que calcular el ancho y darle un padding

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente el compañero SAL, tiene razón es tan sencillo como usar una sub cadena, en todo caso por si le sirve a alguien la forma de hacerlo sería así:

```
<input type="text" name="tkn_sms" id="tkn_sms" value="<?php echo substr($row ['tkn_sms']), 0 ,6);?> ..." class="form-control" >
```

De esta forma, solo muestro los 6 primeros caracteres de la cadena de texto que viene de la BD.

Gracias por las luces amigo SAL.